# Escaping the "<" symbol in Prawn with inline_format enabled

Tags: ruby, prawn

I'm using inline formatting with Prawn, and found a font that gives me the correct symbol, but it uses "<" as the key.

This is a problem as Prawn reads that as formatting information....

Is there a way that either escape the key, or remap the font to a different key?

it's a basic font similar to webdings.

Comment: I'm not sure your question is descriptive enough here: the correct symbol for what? Also, keys are on your keyboard, did you mean it renders the symbol you want based on the input string "<"? Did you remember to first ask about this over at https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn before posting on SO? What was the response?

Comment: i did not know that I could ask questions on their github page, I will try that now. In any case, I want to know how I can type the "<" symbol as part of text with inline_format enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prawn will accept HTML entities, so you can use `&lt;` in place of `<` and `&gt;` in place of `>`.

Comment: I am unable to display pound sign. Prawn isn't able to understand - &#163; Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: A pound sign does not need to be escaped, so just use the £ character directly.